# Find eigenvalue and eigenvector (linear transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear transformation is reflection in the line $y = -4 x$ $(\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$). It has a eigenvector $[1, -4]$ and a corresponding eigenvalue $1$. Find the other eigenvector and its corresponding eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The point $[1,-4]$ is an eigenvector because it lies on the line $y = -4x$, so reflecting it through the line gives you the same point, which is of course a multiple of itself.  So, $[1,-4]$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

What is another point that, when reflected through the line, is mapped to a multiple of itself?  What did we multiply it by (that is, what is the eigenvalue)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The matrix corresponding to the reflection at x axis is
 $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Then rotate the x axis to $y=4x$. Then act by conjugation. Now calculate eigenvalues & eigenvectors.